# Flutter + Firebase Auth: Is there any way to resend the SMS verification code with Firebase phone auth on web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

### Problem

I created a "resend SMS" for my login page on mobile, *which works just fine*, using `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber()` and its `forceResendingToken` property.
When a user presses the "resend SMS" button, the verification code SMS is sent again and the button is disabled for some time (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAmQf.png)).

However, I cannot find anywhere if there is a way to resend the SMS verification code on web. The `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber()` method does not have a property like `forceResendingToken` or something like that. So my question is, **is there a way to resend the verification code SMS on web using Firebase phone authentication?**

I have searched Google, the [Fireflutter documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/) and Stackoverflow but could not find someone with the same question or other relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Firebase will not re-send a new SMS message if it has been recently sent. You can however override this behavior by re-calling the verifyPhoneNumber method with the resend token to the forceResendingToken argument. If successful, the SMS message will be resent.